# How to convert integer months to year in python

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I have inputs start date and end date. I want output like **2 years 7 months**

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
rdelta = relativedelta(now, birthdate)
print 'years - ', rdelta.years
print 'months - ', rdelta.months
```

in this method, I got output like

```
>>> years - 2
>>> months - 18
```

I prefer output like **I want output like 2 years 7 months**

Comment: What is `birthdate` in this case? I can not reproduce this.

Comment: now is the end date and birthdate is the start date. python datetime format

Comment: I get that, but I'm wondering what for *values* did you use for birthday (and now). The birthday is december 2018?

Comment: birthday =  datetime.date(1997, 12, 8)
now =  datetime.date(2021, 7, 8)

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. If I do `rd = relativedelta(years=2, months=7)`  then `rd.years` returns `2` and `rd.months` returns `7`.

Comment: Do you just want to the result being formatted ? `print(f"{rdelta.years} years {rdelta.months} months")` ?

Comment: If I run this locally I got `relativedelta(years=+23, months=+7)`. You seem to use Python-2, but Python-2 is no longer supported since 1-1-2020

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
def format_date_range(start: datetime.date, end: datetime.date):
    rdelta = relativedelta(end, start)
    return f"{rdelta.years} years, {rdelta.months} months"
```

What's the start and end dates here?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what type is `now` and `birthdate`. Assuming they are date objects. It works fine.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import date

birthdate = date(2000, 1, 1)
now  = date(2021, 6, 6)

rdelta = relativedelta(now, later)
print ('years -', rdelta.years)
print ('months -', rdelta.months)
```

For this, I get the following output.

```
years - 21
months - 5
```